# the difference between a[:,None] and a[:,]

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to know more numpy to process array. I find that it is different between a[:,None] and a[:,]. I want to dig into where and when to use them.

I try to slove the problem that subtract 1d from 2d array in special way just like [numpy-subtract-add-1d-array-from-2d-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303348/numpy-subtract-add-1d-array-from-2d-array) where I realise it's different between a[:,None] and a[:,].

---

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> b = np.array([1,2,3])

>>> b
array([1, 2, 3])

>>> b[:,None]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

>>> b[:,]
array([1, 2, 3])

>>> b[None,:]
array([[1, 2, 3]])

>>> a-b[None,:]
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [6, 6, 6]])

>>> b[,:] #false operation!!!
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> a-b
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [6, 6, 6]])

>>> a-b[:,np.newaxis]
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Can anyone give me official or specific reference about it? I will really appreciate you!

Comment: `a[:]` does nothing except return a view of `a`; no change in dimensions (check it).  The trailing `,` in a[:,]` just makes the indexing argument a tuple (that's a basic Python operation), which functionally is the same, a plain view.  `a[,:]` is a syntax error.  That's raised by interpreter; that's not a `numpy` issue.

Comment: Thank for your recommendation! I  has already checked it. You are right, but it does is numpy issue, becasue python 3.x does not support tuple as list indices.

Comment: Syntax errors are raised by the Python interpreter.  `[1,2,3][:,]` raises a TypeError, `x[,:]` or `x[,3]` raises a syntax error, regardless of what `x` is.  I think the relevant syntax specification is `target_list` in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements.  Even outside of indexing `(,2)` and `[,34]` are wrong.

Comment: Ahhh! You hit the nail! Yeah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess instead of `None` you should use `np.newaxis`, which is actually the same, but with `np.newaxis` the code is more readable, as it inserts a new axis at this dimension.

See:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis